# C# Sharp Grade program using for and while

Tags: c#

I'm new at C# and am having trouble with nested loops. I'm working on a Grading program with a menu. The first menu asks the user how many grades would they like to enter. Then, the user enters the grades. The Second menu figures out the average and grade. I'm having trouble with a nested loop where it would ask you a given number of time to enter grades.

Once that is done, I'm also having trouble with how I would pass that info to the second menu to get the average. I done something like this better in Java, but there we had a set number of grades; then, we made a variable for each grade. Finally we summed them and divided by a set number.

```
bool exit = false;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. Enter Grades");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Get Average");
    Console.WriteLine("3. My program");
    Console.WriteLine("4. exit");

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("");

    if (input == "1")
    {
        int totalGrades = 0;
        double grades;
        double grade, finalGrade = 0;

        //User Input
        Console.WriteLine("How many grades do you want to enter? ");

        //While loop for TryParse
        while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out totalGrades))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
        }

        while (totalGrades < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Grade: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 0; i<= totalGrades; totalGrades++)

            Console.WriteLine(totalGrades);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else if (input == "2")
    {
        double average = 0;

        if (average >= 90)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an A.");
        }
        else if (average >= 80)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an B.");
        }
        else if (average >= 70)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an C.");
        }
        else if (average >= 60)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an D.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an E.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit = true;
    }
} 
while (exit == false);
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly? You've said you're having trouble but haven't explained what that trouble is at all.

Comment: The Menu should only have 1-3 I was playing around with "3. My program" that will be deleted.

Comment: Enter Grade not working right. It just loops adding number over and over. I only get to enter one number then it goes in infit loop.

Comment: Java and c Sharp 's syntaxes are really close so there should be no problem with a simple conversion.

Comment: once I get that working then I can start working on adding grades to get sum. Then divide to get Average. Then run that thru part 2 to get grade.

Comment: In the `for` loop, `totalGrades++` should be `i++`. You're moving the limit away from the counter rather than progressing the counter toward the limit.

Comment: But I need some how to add up the totalgrades for I can figure out average.

Comment: *"But"*... Sure, do so within the `for` loop, but making sure that the loop actually iterates the correct number of times is your first concern.

Comment: Also, `while (totalGrades < 1)` isn't necessary where it is, but if you want to ensure that `totalGrades` is at least 1, add `|| totalGrades < 1` to the first `while` loop's condition, so that failing to parse *or* correctly parsing 0 or negative will ask again.

Comment: You will have much better luck getting an answer if you have a specific issue. It is likely that if you ask a specific problem and get an answer to that, that you may then be able to figure out some of your other issues.

Comment: when I run it, I enter 1, then it ask me How many grades do you want to enter? if I enter 5, but it never ask me Enter Grade.

Comment: 1. Enter Grades
2. Get Average
3. My program
4. exit
1

How many grades do you want to enter?
5

Comment: `while (totalGrades < 1)` What do you think that line of code does?

Answer (score 1):

I've changed a few things in order to make the code easier to understand.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProgramLoop();
    }

    private static void ProgramLoop()
    {
        var grades = new List<double>();
        double average;
        var exit = false;

        do
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("1. Enter Grades");
            System.Console.WriteLine("2. Get Average");
            System.Console.WriteLine("3. My program");
            System.Console.WriteLine("4. exit");

            var input = System.Console.ReadLine();

            System.Console.WriteLine("");

            switch (input)
            {
                case "1":
                    grades = EnterGrades();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    average = GetAverage(grades);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    MyProgram();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    exit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.Console.WriteLine($"'{input}' is not a valid choice.");
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (exit == false);
    }

    private static List<double> EnterGrades()
    {
        int numberOfGrades = 0;
        var grades = new List<double>();

        System.Console.WriteLine("How many grades do you want to enter? ");

        // Read number of grades
        while (!int.TryParse(System.Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfGrades) || numberOfGrades < 1)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
        }

        while (grades.Count != numberOfGrades)
        {
            // Read grade
            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Grade: ");
            double grade;

            while (!double.TryParse(System.Console.ReadLine(), out grade) || grade < 0 || grade > 100)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid grade between 0.0 and 100.0");
            }

            grades.Add(grade);
        }

        return grades;
    }

    private static double GetAverage(IList<double> grades)
    {
        var average = grades.Average();

        if (average >= 90)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"The average is {average}, which is an A.");
        }
        else if (average >= 80)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"The average is {average}, which is an B.");
        }
        else if (average >= 70)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"The average is {average}, which is an C.");
        }
        else if (average >= 60)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"The average is {average}, which is an D.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"The average is {average}, which is an E.");
        }

        return average;
    }
```

I would recommend you to split your code into methods. The code will be easier to understand, and it's a great practice to not cram too much code together.

If you plan on adding more functionality and write more code, I would also recommend you to look into how you can apply object oriented programming to this, i.e. writing classes like a GradeCard.

Comment: Code looks good. It looks like you are using list and creating (python-functions or java-methods) new at C# show not sure what they are called. We are not that far into C# yet. But I think that is what we are going to do soon with this code break it down to methods.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple things I'd like to highlight and I also added notes to the code. You want to keep 2 variables throughout your program/method to keep track of everything entered. They are the 2 pieces of average (1) Total and (2) Count of input numbers. See the code and read it line by line and see the comments. Hope this helps you. Feel free to ask questions if something doesn't make sense.

```
bool exit = false;

// added variables outside of loop so they are available everywhere in the method
double grades = 0;
int gradesCount = 0;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. Enter Grades");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Get Average");
    Console.WriteLine("3. exit");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("");


    if (input == "1")
    {
        int totalGrades = 0;

        //User Input
        Console.WriteLine("How many grades do you want to enter? ");

        //While loop for TryParse
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out totalGrades))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
        }

        // increment the count of grades by the number of grades the user wants to add
        gradesCount += totalGrades;

        // variable to keep a count and avoid infinite loop
        int addedGradesCount = 0;

        // while loop works like a for loop using our variable to keep count of grades we add
        while (addedGradesCount < totalGrades)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Grade: ");

            // variable to store entered grade
            double newGrade = 0;

            //Reusing code from while loop above for TryParse
            while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out newGrade))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
            }

            // increment running total of grades with the user input number
            grades += newGrade;

            // output to user - got rid of loop through totalGrades
            Console.WriteLine("You entered: " + newGrade + " - Total: " + grades);

            // increment variable to keep count! if this is not here, you will have infinite loop
            addedGradesCount++;
        }
        // Console.ReadLine(); // not needed
    }
    else if (input == "2")
    {
        // calculate average using the method variables we initialized at the beginning
        double average = (grades / gradesCount);

        if (average >= 90)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an A.");
        }
        else if (average >= 80)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an B.");
        }
        else if (average >= 70)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an C.");
        }
        else if (average >= 60)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an D.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an E.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit = true;
    }
} while (exit == false);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks will now read line by line and see what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Here gradesCount += totalGrades;  why could you not just say gradesCount = totalGrades;

Comment: @Doogie `gradesCount += totalGrades` is equivalent to `gradesCount = gradesCount + totalGrades`. I did this to keep the long running total over multiple runs of the user entering grades. Situation: User selects option 1 to input grades, then pulls an average, then selects option 1 again. By adding the new `totalGrades` value from the second run to the running total, we can average everything the user has input so far. `gradesCount = totalGrades` would reset the count of grades entered every time option 1 is selected. Does this make sense?

Comment: When running the program it should reset each time after selecting option 2 and get grade. When they run option again it should start over. I have tried  gradesCount += totalGrades; and  gradesCount = totalGrades; both still keep a running total. I have tried moving and adding the variable outside the loop but get error when it calls for variable in option 2. My goal is to have it setup each time after option 2 gives grade. They could option 1 and do another students grades.

Comment: Okay. `gradesCount = totalGrades` should do what you're looking for. If not, try setting `gradesCount = 0` right before setting totalGrades to that variable. If that doesn't work, you have another error.

Comment: That does not work. Right now gradesCount is at the top outside the loop. It I put it inside loop then Menu #2 can not use it and get error.

Comment: The point of having it outside the loop is so you can access that variable from both menu options 1 and 2. What is the issue with keeping it there?

Comment: I understand that but I need away to reset it back to 0. Right now when you run the program it takes the grades and adds them up. Then when you click menu 2 it gives you your average. Which works. But then if I go back to menu 1 and add more grades it adds those grades to the grades you already enter the first time. It should start all over to give you a new grade.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that. You can simply set it equal to the new count by `gradesCount = totalGrades` and also reset your running total `grades = 0`. Just reset your variables before you set them (upon menu #1)

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool exit = false;
        List<float> grades = new List<float>();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. Enter Grades");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Get Average");
            Console.WriteLine("3. My program");
            Console.WriteLine("4. exit");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("");

            if (input == "1")
            {
                int totalGrades = 0;

                //User Input
                Console.WriteLine("How many grades do you want to enter? ");
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        totalGrades = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (FormatException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid number");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");

                while (totalGrades > 0)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            grades.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
                            totalGrades--;
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (FormatException)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid number");
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else if (input == "2")
            {

                double average = grades.Average();

                if (average >= 90)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an A.");
                }
                else if (average >= 80)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an B.");
                }
                else if (average >= 70)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an C.");
                }
                else if (average >= 60)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an D.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"The average is a {average} which is an E.");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("");

            }
            else if (input == "4")
            {
                exit = true;
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not an option");
            }
        }
        while (exit == false);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Rob Bieman - Please can you add some text to your answer - explain how it works and why it answers the question. Generally code-only questions are frowned upon here.

Comment: Moreover, using try/catch in this manner is widely discouraged, and something better like `int.TryParse` was *already being used*.